# Using Variables For Input

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm currently using this code to make presidential projections:

```
require 'csv'
require 'statistics2'
require 'pollster'
require 'uri'
include Pollster

poll = Poll.where(:chart => '2016-national-gop-primary').first
responses = poll.questions.detect { |question| question.chart == '2016-national-gop-primary' }.responses
rubio = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Rubio" }
bush = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Bush" }
walker = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Walker" }
carson = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Carson" }
huckabee = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Huckabee" }
paul = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Paul" }
cruz = responses.detect { |response| response[:choice] == "Cruz" }

difference = rubio[:value] - walker[:value]
negativechance = Statistics2.tdist(2,(difference/3)) 
nchance = 1 - (Statistics2.tdist(2,(difference/3)))

if difference < 0
then puts "#{nchance.to_f*100}""%" + " Walker."
     puts "#{(1-nchance.to_f)*100}""%" + " Rubio."
     puts "Based on latest poll at Pollster.com"
else puts "#{negativechance.to_f*100}}""%" "Rubio."
     puts "#{(1-negativechance.to_f)*100}""%" + " Walker."
     puts "Based on latest poll at Pollster.com"
end
```

I want the user to be able to input two last names to find the projection for who will win. If I change this:

```
difference = rubio[:value] - walker[:value]
```

to variables it tells me I don't have a value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does responses look like? (me == #ruby baweaver)

Comment: responses - https://gist.github.com/AthleteInvictus/57e337e222b4bde87235

Answer (score 0):

That looks an awful lot like a KV pair (Hash), so what if you make choice the key and value the value? Using that key you can get dynamic choices very easily, but you're going to have to do some legwork here yourself.

You need to go from this:

```
[{a: 'foo', b: 1}, {a: 'bar', b: 21}, {a: 'baz', b: 13}]
```

To this:

```
{'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 21, 'baz' => 13}
```

Hint: You're going to need map and to_h

```
[[:a, 1]].to_h # => {a: 1}
```